# Visual Basic How to reference a dynamically created button

Tags: vb.net

My code creates 40 buttons dynamically I can change properties if the button is clicked using sender but how do I reference them when I click a different button

```
Public Sub loadButtons()


    For i As Integer = 0 To 39

        If i > 19 Then
            gap = i + 10
        Else
            gap = i
        End If
        Dim B As New Button
        Form1.panSeats.Controls.Add(B)

        B.Height = 30
        B.Width = 37
        B.Left = ((i Mod 10) * 47) + 322
        B.Top = ((gap \ 10) * 31) + 114

        B.Text = Chr((i \ 10) + Asc("A")) & i Mod 10 + 1
        B.Tag = i
        Buttons.Add(B.Text, B)
        If isBooked(i) = True Then


            B.BackColor = Color.Red
        Else
            B.BackColor = Color.Orange
        End If
        AddHandler B.Click, AddressOf Form1.Button_Click
    Next

End Sub
```

I want to be able to change the backcolor B isn't declared have tried using the button.tag but not working

```
Private Sub btnTestCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTestCancel.Click

    B.BackColor = Color.Orange
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to change the backcolor of _all of them_, or just one? If the latter, which one?

Answer (score 1):

The `Addhandler` statement wires the events for all dynamically added buttons. The `sender` object is the one being clicked, we just need to unbox it.

```
AddHandler B.Click, AddressOf btns_Click

Private Sub btns_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 'no handles clause needed
  Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
  btn.BackColor = Color.Orange
End Sub
```

Comment: `sender` and `Button` both are reference types, so you can not "unbox" them. You just casting reference of type `object` to the reference of type `Button`. Unboxing is process which check and then copy "boxed" value of value type from the instance to the value type variable.